# BASH script help using TOP, GREP and CUT

Tags: bash, shell, grep, cut

Use **Top** command which repeats 5 times, pipe the results to **Grep** and **Cut** command to print the PID for *init* process on your screen.

Hi all, I have my line of code:

```
top -n 5 | grep "init" | cut -d" " -f3 > topdata
```

But I cannot see any output to verify that it's working.
Also, the next script asks me to use a one line command which shows the total memory used in megabytes. I'm supposed to pipe results from Free to Grep to select or filter the lines with the pattern "Total:" then pipe that result to Cut and display the number representing total memory used. So far:

```
free -m -t | grep "total:" | cut -c25-30
```

Also not getting any print return on that one. Any help appreciated.

Comment: 1) grep is case sensitive.  free says "Total", you grep "total".  So no match!  Either grep for "Total" or use grep -i.

Comment: 2) Instead of cut, I prefer awk when I need to get a number out of a line.  You do not know what length the number will be, but you know it will be the first number after Total:.  So:  free -m -t | grep "Total:" | awk '{print $2}'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

expanding on my comments:

1. grep is case sensitive. free says "Total", you grep "total". So no match! Either grep for "Total" or use grep -i.
2. Instead of cut, I prefer awk when I need to get a number out of a line. You do not know what length the number will be, but you know it will be the first number after Total:. So:

`free -m -t | grep "Total:" | awk '{print $2}'`

3. For your top command, if you have no init process (which you should, but it would probably not show in top), just grep for something else to see if your code works.  I used cinnamon (running Mint).  The top command is:

`top -n 5 | grep "cinnamon" | awk '{print $1}'`

Replace "cinnamon" by "init" for your requirement.  Why $1 in the awk?  My top puts the PID in the first column.  Adjust accordingly.

Overall, using cut is good when you have a string that is delimited by some character.  Ex. aaa;bbb;ccc, you would cut on -d';'.  But here the numbers might have different lengths so using cut is not (IMHO) the best solution.

Comment: Nic3500, thank you. However, for this practice assignment we are supposed to use those commands and not awk or sed.

Comment: Ah ok so use cut with positionnal arguments like you posted, that can work.  Your grep for free was wrong anyway and explains the lack of output.

Comment: For init, it will not show up in top very high since it uses 0 cpu, so it will only appear at the total end of the top list.  Top shows the highest use CPU commands, so init will not appear very his.

Comment: Or use:  top -p 1.  PID of init is 1, so top will only monitor that one.

Comment: no matter how this is phrased, i get no output. for example:
top -n 5 -p 1 | grep "init" | cut -d" " -f5
does nothing...it is repeating top 5 times as asked, but no output at all, whereas when i use "netns" i do get output. maybe the VM is screwy

Comment: Do a `ps -ef | grep init`. Do you have an init process?  You should...  Take that pid in your top command.

Comment: I don't actually have anything but kdeinit, kdminit and etc/alsa/alsactl.conf --initfile=/lib/alsa/init/00main rdaemon

Answer (score 0):

The `init` process has PID 1, to there's no reason to do like this.

To find the PID of a process in general, I'd recommend:

```
pidof <name>
```

Comment: While you are right for the pidof command, that is not what the OP was asking (well incomplete answer).

Comment: @Nic3500 I answered ONE of OP:s questions. And after all, you should not ask more than one question in a question.